# OSX application with python backend

Tags: python, xcode, macos, pyobjc

I am interested in developing a GUI application for OSX but would like, if possible, to avoid learning Obj. C or swift.  I have the backend of the program written in python.  Is there a good way of using xcode (and particularly the interface builder) to link up the GUI to the python backend?
P.s. I have come across PyObjC but the documentation *sucks* so I'm trying to avoid it.
Cheers,
Jack

Comment: I would suggest PyQt

Comment: Is there any reason you want to use Xcode in particular?

Comment: My main motivation is that by using the interface builder you can very quickly make a gui.  I had played around with tkinter but it looked terrible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your background and your motivations I would use [PyQt](http://fr.wikibooks.org/wiki/PyQt) with [Qt Creator](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/) which contains a nice interface builder :

[image]

Comment: great shout.  Easier than xcode and still creates sharp looking guis without learning an exclusively apple language!